# How does Zoom Attendee Attention Tracking (Window Focus Tracking) work?

Tags: window, focus, tracking, privacy

I just heard about [this](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/115000538083-Attendee-Attention-Tracking) feature on Zoom Meeting and found it a bit puzzling. Do any of you guys have thoughts on how exactly this would work? It seems like window focus isn't something that should be shared by default. Also, it says that the feature only works in their desktop client on windows / mac, so is installation writing some registry changes? If so, any insight on how it works and why it doesn't work on linux?

Comment: Surely there's no problem with the app knowing that it's not in focus at the moment. It doesn't need to know *which* program has the focus, only that it doesn't have it.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on my original question? Whether it's problematic or not - I'm still curious about how it works!

Comment: It's a basic feature provided by the OS.

Comment: Hmm, okay do you have any suggestions on things to read if I wanted to understand it in a bit more depth than that?